# String equals commands do not line up with rows of source tsv file

Tags: java, string, processing

I am coding a simple diagram that parses a .tsv file that has 6 columns and 9 rows. I am attempting to put some text on my diagram that is coloured according to the data existing in the third column. I am able to get all the colours on the screen, but for some reason, the text that ends up red is the text corresponding to the row (in the tsv file) BELOW the row whose text I want to be red. For example, while I want the Liberal candidate to have a fill of (200,60,60), the Parti Quebecois candidate appearing in the row below instead becomes red. Following, the New Dem party candidate ends up with the fill of (155,191,219). The code appears as follows:

```
PImage mapOfCanada; // background map
Premier[] premiers; // premiers data

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  // modified mapOfCanada from http://www.theblog.ca/map-canada
  mapOfCanada = loadImage("bigmapofcanada.png");
  // from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_Canadian_first_ministers
  Table table = new Table("premiers.tsv");
  int rows = table.getRowCount();
  premiers = new Premier[rows];
  // read through each row of the source data to populate our premiers array
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    String name = table.getString(i, 0);
    String province = table.getString(i, 1);
    String party = table.getString(i, 2);
    String imgFile = table.getString(i, 3);
    PImage img = loadImage(imgFile);
    float x = table.getFloat(i,4);
    float y = table.getFloat(i,5);
    premiers[i] = new Premier(name, province, party, img, x, y);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // draw the background image with a light tint
  tint(255, 25);
  image(mapOfCanada, 0, 0);

  // draw each premier
  noTint();
  for (Premier premier : premiers) {
    image(premier.img, premier.x, premier.y);
  }
  //drawing lines for those premier images that cannot fit in the alloted province space
  line(158,560,145,460); //Alberta
  line(300,560,340,500); //Manitoba
  line(650,365,670,410); //Newfoundland
  line(750,385,710,535); //PEI
  line(730,575,720,550); //Nova Scotia
  line(670,595,680,560); //New Brunswick

  //adding text labels
  for (Premier premier : premiers) { //reading through the source data in a loop
   textSize(10); //making the text size small yet readable
   textAlign(CENTER); //making sure the text is centered above the image
    text(premier.name, premier.x+50, premier.y-10); //positioning the text in relation to the x and y coordinates on the source data

{
String string1 = new String("Liberal");
String string2 = new String("Parti Quebecois");
String string3 = new String("New Democratic");
String string4 = new String ("Progressive Conservative");
String string5 = new String ("Saskatchewan Party");
String string6 = new String ("Yukon Party");

if (premier.party.equals("Liberal")) {
  fill(200,60,60);  
} 
else if (premier.party.equals("Parti Quebecois")) {
  fill(155,191,219);
}
else if (premier.party.equals("New Democratic")) {
  fill(180,151,107);
}
else if(premier.party.equals("Progressive Conservative")) {
  fill(96,104,250);
}
else if(premier.party.equals("Saskatchewan Party")) {
  fill (107,180,119);
}
else if(premier.party.equals("Yukon Party")) {
  fill (47,85,232);
}
  else {
  fill (0,0,0);
}
}
  }
}

class Premier {
  String name, province, party;
  PImage img; // this is the thumbnail image
  float x, y; // these are the coordinates for the thumbnail
  Premier(String name, String province, String party, PImage img, float x, float y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.province = province;
    this.party = party;
    this.img = img;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Any help re: what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated! I've edited the post to feature the full code.

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is no problem in the code you have given above. The problem may be in the premier.party value you have get from the file. Some file format will not parse correctly as per our requirement. So check it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a one off error in the loop that wraps the code that you have posted.

Comment: The loop begins like this:
    `for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    String name = table.getString(i, 0);
    String province = table.getString(i, 1);
    String party = table.getString(i, 2);
    String imgFile = table.getString(i, 3);
    PImage img = loadImage(imgFile);
    float x = table.getFloat(i,4);
    float y = table.getFloat(i,5);
    premiers[i] = new Premier(name, province, party, img, x, y);`


Does that help?

Comment: The portion of code that is problematic is not the one that you have posted. The problem could be in fill().

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of an issue you're having, it may be related to indexing error - i.e. using 0-based indexing where it's actually 1-based or vice versa. But without the loop code and fill() code it will be very hard to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: That was my hunch as well. I amended the original post to include my full code. The O-based indexing is used, but in the case where the text and images themselves are coded to appear (with source data from the tsv) they work out fine. it's only the if equals statements with the fill() that mess up.